# What neutralizes the active ingredients (napthalene and/or paradichlorobenzene) in moth balls?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, cleaning

Question: What is effective in removing residual moth ball smell from inside a car?

Issue: We used moth balls in our car to rid it of mice. (Never do this; it does not work.) We removed the moth balls after about a month. The car, free of moth balls for three months, still reeks of the moth ball smell. After driving in the car for 10-15 minutes, our clothes also smell like moth balls and require washing to rid them of the smell. Would airing the car out be effective or do I need to be more drastic?

Comment: Let air circulate for a long time (days) if outside temperature allows it. Naphtalene sublimes (goes from solid state to gas) and the bad odor should vanish. Otherwise is internal washing possible?

Comment: In summer, expose your car to the hot sun until it's heated up. Then open the car doors (don't let the mice in again) to exchange the air. Repeat the procedure until the smell is gone.